# Is it possible to bind a DropDownList on OnLoad method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I have a dynamic table with many DropDownLists which have dynamic 'ids'. I need to bind them when they are selected but the method OnLoad doesn't work. It works with OnClick but it's not the better way to do that.

This is my DropDown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("reagB-" + const.Id, new SelectList(new List<Reagente>(), "Id ", "Nome"), Resources.Geral.Selecione, new { onchange = "SelecionaReagente($(this));", onclick = "OnClickReagente($(this), " + (resultado != null ? resultado.ReagenteId : 0) + ");", onLoad = "OnLoadReagente($(this));" })
```

And this is my jquery code:

```
function OnClickReagente(cbo, ReagenteId) {
var gcId = cbo.attr("id").split('-')[1];

$("#reagB-" + gcId + " option").remove();

$.ajax({
    url: "/Grupo/ComboReagentes",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        grupoConstituinteId: gcId,
        equipamentoId: cbo.val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var cboReagente = $("#reagB-" + gcId);

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            if (item.Id == ReagenteId && ReagenteId > 0) {
                cboReagente.append("<option value='" + item.Id + " selected='selected''>" + item.Nome + "</option>");
            } else {
                cboReagente.append("<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + item.Nome + "</option>");
            }
        });                        
    }
})
```

}

When I select the dropdown the OnClick is called but it occurs every time I select the dropdown. What I need is to load de dropdown only in the first click. Today it's working in another way but I need to improve the performance.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do something once and not on subsequent events, see if  [jquery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is of any help.

Comment: You need to run the `OnLoadReagente` function the first time someone clicks on the `Select` with `id` "reagB-" + const.Id and not on subsequent clicks, is that what you want?

Comment: @Mathew I did this: `$("select").one("click", function () { alert('selected'); });`, so the alert is shown once but then every time I select the DropDown it's binded again.

Comment: Maybe because you put that code in `onchange`. You do that in document ready and see if that helps.

Comment: @Mathew, I did that in `document ready` and my Select has an onclick method!

Comment: You can remove `onclick` attribute and use the jquery code alone right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42516/discussion-between-deise-vicentin-and-mathew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jquery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for your purpose,

```
$(function(){ 
       $(".dropdown-class").one("click",function(){//call the method you specified in onclick here}) 
});
```